# Structure paragraphs a bit more

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

I often try to group paragraphs together with `\\[0.5cm]`. For example I have a section with 5 paragraphs and I think the first two and the last three are more connected with each other I would group it like this:

```
\section{Title}
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla 

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla \\[0.5cm]

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla 

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla 

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla 

\section{Next title}
```

I'am quite sure this is not a good habit, since LaTeX gives a lot of "underfull \hbox" errors. I don't think it would be a good idea to use `\subsection{}`, since the paragraphs still belongs together, even some just belong a bit more together than others ;)

My questions are:

1. Is it a good practice / acceptable at all to structure the paragraphs like that?
2. How would be the proper way of doing this. I already thought of `\vfill`, `\paragraph{}` (with no title) and \vspace{}.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I too use such bigger paragraph separators.  `\\[1.5ex]` or `\\[1em]` would be better than `\\[0.5cm]` as the former two are relative to your font size size. Secondly, this space would mean a lot of space in addition to the normal paragraph separator length `\parsep`. So, I use `\\[-0.5ex]` instead. Finally, have you tried `\smallskip`, `\medskip` and `\bigskip` at the end of a paragraph after which you want to leave a gap ?

Comment: It is very bad practice to do so (rule of thumb: never use `\\ ` outside of a tabular). Usually one would either define an own environment to structure the content (even if the environment just inserts some space afterwards). Alternatively, have a look at the skip commands Partha D. mentioned.

Comment: The `memoir` class provides for *anonymous breaks* whereby paragraphs can be separated by either blank lines or by symbols. In general using extra space between sets of paragraphs is not a good idea (what if the extra space occurs at the bottom or top of a page? Who would notice?) See *Fancy anonymous breaks* in the `memoir` manual (`> texdoc memoir`).

Comment: Do you have any news for us?

Comment: I ended up was just using `\bigskip`...